# Enable outbound active ftp for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp

I'm trying to FTP out using a php script on EC2.
When using passive mode it works great but it fails in active mode.
I've tried opening high ports in EC2 security group but it's still not working.
What do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: Can I ask: Why in the world are you still using FTP? [FTP Must Die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Comment: I agree with the sentiment but my app has to support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do active FTP from PHP, you will need at least three things to be in place:

1. Data port to be open in the EC2 security group - which you have
2. Your script should send out the external IP address of the EC2 instance and not the internal IP (10.x.x.x)
3. You must explicitly set the active option in whichever library you are using for FTP

Comment: I think the problem is 2 - how do I solve that? BTW not using a library, but php's built-in ftp extensions.

Comment: It would depend on the FTP client (PHP library) that you are using, or play around with the server configuration (not recommended).

Comment: PHP's bult-in ftp http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: You're probably out of luck on EC2 unless you want to patch the PHP extension code yourself.  Some 'smarter' firewalls will do Layer 7 tinkering and change the IP address transparently but apparently EC2 does not do it.

Comment: I think you're right. I wonder if I can use ftp_raw or curl. Really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: I have not used it, but from a cursory look, curl may have the options you need.